# Does SFDC serve the entire zip static resource, or just the resources referenced?

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

When I inspect a page in Chrome/Firefox, I don't see the entire zip file as a requested resource. Only the files referenced are served to the client side.

Does SFDC unzip resources server-side before serving them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Web browsers don't know how to deal with zip files (as built-in media types, opposed to JPG, GIF, and CSS, for example), and so they can't be served to the user directly. Salesforce automatically decompresses and serves just that one file from the resource. What's not documented is if this is done by cache or by on-demand, but the end result is the same-- the client is served only files the developer requested. This also reduces the overall bandwidth required by only transferring necessary resources.